# Implement PfSense Firewall (Help for assign network adapter interfaces)

Tags: firewall

I want to deploy a firewall as an operating system on a hyperv machine in an existing network that currently has access to the internet through a Mikrotik router board and the router board has access to the internet through 3 different isp's and my goal is Providing a firewall between these routers so that it can monitor all communication paths with the outside of the network. The Mikrotik board router and anyone who wants to access the Internet must access the outside of the network through the firewall.
Range: 192.168.0.0/19
My problem is in appointing the type of virtual network card in hyperway, so that I want a network card to have access to the open Internet through Internet modems so that it can direct requests from the internal network to the open Internet, and a network card through the Kor router. Mikrotik has access to the internal network.

It is worth mentioning that the above implementation method may not be correct, if you have a better implementation suggestion, please suggest it in the comments.

If it is possible to put a firewall in the explanatory conditions, what changes should be made in the Mikrotik router so that the Internet connection of the network users will not be interrupted after starting the above scenario.

Comment: Do you want to *replace* the Mikrotik router or put the pfSense *behind* the Mikrotik?

Comment: i want add firewall between Mikrotik and ISP routers